# where are Thunderbird sent read receipts logged?

Tags: linux, email, microsoft-outlook, thunderbird, email-client

Does Thunderbird log receipts which are sent?  If so, where?

I've modified my options to send read receipts, but am looking for records of what was sent in the past, in particular to outlook.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such facility or record